# Unable to write a Filter which serves for Login

Tags: servlets

I have written a filter and declared it under web.xml as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<filter>
    <display-name>SessionAuthenticationFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>SessionAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.jsp.auth.SessionAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>skipthis</param-name>
      <param-value>01-login.html</param-value>
    </init-param> 
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is my FILTER File

```
package com.jsp.auth;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
public class SessionAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
     private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;
    public SessionAuthenticationFilter() {
    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String loginpageuri = filterConfig.getInitParameter("skipthis");
        String requesturi = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println("The requesturi is"+requesturi);
        if(!requesturi.endsWith(loginpageuri))
       {
           String isloggoed = (String)session.getAttribute("LOGIN_USER");
           System.out.println("The isloggoed value is"+isloggoed);

        if(isloggoed==null||isloggoed.equals("")||isloggoed.isEmpty())
        {
            response.sendRedirect("http://xxx.xx.xx:8080/admin/01-login.html");
            return ;
        }
        else
        {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
       }
        else
        {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
      }
}
```

These are the logs i am getting in my server console . (**Its blocking all the .css .js files also**)

```
The isloggoed value isnull
The requesturi is/AdminE/assets/css/style-metro.css
The isloggoed value isnull
The requesturi is/AdminE/assets/css/style-responsive.css
The isloggoed value isnull
The requesturi is/AdminE/assets/css/themes/default.css
The isloggoed value isnull
```

Incase if i change the url-pattern to this way in my web.xml 
    **/*.html**

I am getting HTTP Status 404 - /AdminE/01-login.html

Could anybody please help me how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Java Servlet Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/), the `url-pattern` should be:

> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>     `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’ and
>     the servlet path and context path is empty string ("").
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

So according to this, the pattern `/*.html` will be interpreted literally and the `*` will not act as a wildcard. Try with `*.html` instead (no leading slash).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you are trying to use a filter as a login service protecting a whole application. If you do not want to re-invent the wheel, you could also have a look to the excellent [shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) or [Spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).

If you prefer to roll your own, you should give your filter more parameters :

- the address of the login page (it must let it pass through and redirects to it when not previously logged) - ok you have it
- a list of patterns to ignore because the servlet specification (see David Levesque's answer) is not versatile enough - alternatively you can use a positive logic giving a list of patterns to filter. It will be much simpler to use simple extensions (.js, .css, .gif, ...) than full patterns because then, `String.endsWith` is enough.

I also advise you to do all the parameters management in `Filter.init` method instead of repeating it for every request. Typically in your code, the attribute should be `String loginpageuri`, and `init` method should be :

```
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    loginpageuri = filterConfig.getInitParameter("skipthis");
}
```